# get_client() got unexpected keyword 'tried' in Django Cache

Tags: python, django, caching, celery

I am getting an error on `cache.set(key, value, time_expire)`

Here is my code:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache_key = 'unique keyname'
res = cache.get(cache_key)
# res data is None

res = 'some data'
cache.set(cache_key, res, 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
```

**Settings.py**

```
# Cache servers
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'redis-ha-1/'
                    'IP1,'
                    'IP2,'
                    'IP3'
                    '/1',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis_sentinel.SentinelClient',
        }
    }
}
```

But on `cache.set` I am getting

> get_client() got unexpected keyword 'tried'

The code is being run through Celery.

```
Django==1.10.5
django-celery==3.2.2
celery==3.1.25
django-redis==4.7.0
django-redis-sentinel==1.0
```

What can be issue ?

**EDIT**

I used command:

```
pip install django-redis-sentinel --upgrade
```

Here is result:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: django-redis-sentinel in /lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: django-redis>=3.8.0 in /lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-redis-sentinel) (4.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: redis>=2.10.0 in /lib/python2.7/site-packages (from django-redis>=3.8.0->django-redis-sentinel) (2.10.6)
```

Comment: maybe a full stack trace can help? there's not much here that could explain the problem.

Comment: just getting this error in the exception and nothing else.
Even I reboot the cache servers.

Comment: Looks like django-redis-sentinel has not been updated for four years and is deprecated. I doubt it is compatible with any recent version of Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman See Edited question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman meant that the pypi package had not been updated for four years (not that your local had not been).

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with versions. Tried param was depricated and removed, so django redis version you use is already updated, but some package you use is not and tries to pass this param.

stacktrace will tell you where or what is "OLD" or just rollback django-redis to 4.5? I am not sure but I think it was ok.